# Failing to parse correctly when using Boost.Spirit

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I am working on a programming language ([full project here](https://github.com/nesteruk/tlon)) implemented using Boost.Spirit, and I am struggling with the following problem. I have the following declaration for a function (line 77 in [this file](https://github.com/nesteruk/Tlon/blob/master/src/Compiler/parser.hpp?line=77)):

```
function_body_rule %=
  identifier_rule
  >> lit(L":=")
  >> lit(L"(")
  >> -parameter_declaration_rule % ','
  >> lit(L")")
  //>> lit(L"->") // epic fail if you uncomment this
  >> type_specification_rule
  >> lit(L"{")
  >> *(assignment_statement_rule)
  >> lit(L"}");
```

At some point, it simply has two tokens one after another. If I uncomment the second token, my function is no longer parsed correctly when I type in the correct sequence. If I comment the token, everything is fine (though I obviously cannot include `->`).

Can you help me figure out what's going on?

Comment: @jv_ you didn't uncomment the line I commented. uncomment it and try with `...:string) -> string...`

Comment: I accidentally copied a previous version. [This one](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/71LKZpNfqrn9TP8y) has it uncommented.

Comment: @jv_ fails for me (boost 1.59)

Comment: I tested it on 1.60 and 1.61, so that seems to be the problem.

Comment: @jv_ didn't help but I relized what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer - the keyboard input rewrote the dash into a − (minus).